# nexus n3k ntp access list

Tags: cisco-nx-os

i have a n3k-3064 with the following access list :

```
10 permit IP 1.2.3.4/32 any
20 deny IP any any
```

and i have assigned this acl to ntp with the following commands :

```
show ntp access-groups
--------------------------------------
Access List                     Type
--------------------------------------
switch-input                    Peer
switch-input                    Serve
```

so my ntp is only restricted to 1.2.3.4/32 which is available in acl and unauthorized IPs can not reach my switch ntp , right?
thank you.

Comment: Your switch is only going to peer or use an NTP server that you have configured. You can also set up authentication, but time is not proprietary, and any NTP server is willing to serve NTP to any client that requests it. I'm not sure what you really want to accomplish. If you only want that address as an NTP server, then only configure that address as an NTP server in your switch, and the switch will not use any other NTP server, but that does not require an ACL.

Comment: An ACL is necessary to keep the switch from acting as an NTP server, or answering management queries.

Comment: if you check my show ntp access-groups output you will see i have set acl, do i set it correctly?